# What's the difference whether or not to run PHP in safe mode?

Tags: php, php-safe-mode

Can you list any specific difference that can be perceived?

Comment: *(reference)* http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php

Answer (score 3):

Safe mode is deprecated, so don't use it.

Comment: There's a pretty good discussion of its flaws here: http://ilia.ws/archives/18_PHPs_safe_mode_or_how_not_to_implement_security.html

Comment: Good stuff Frank. Safe_Model is definitely one of PHP's whipping boys.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, [A whole bunch of functions get disabled.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.functions.php)

Answer (score 1):

There's a full list of restrictions [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.functions.php).

Answer (score 0):

Most functions that interact with the file system get taken away with safe_mode on.

[features.safe-mode.functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.functions.php)